# what to use for php documentation generation?

Tags: php, phpdoc

What do you use for automatic PHP docs generation.

I know about phpdocumentor. but it looks like it didn't have a single release within 2010.
Should I just use it or are there any alternatives?

Comment: phpdocumentor is the standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using DocBlox, a Documentation Generation application inspired on phpDocumentor.
Please see http://www.docblox-project.org for the website and/or http://demo.docblox-project.org/default for a demo.

Comment: I like that brand new shining spunky super-duper-delicious template!

Answer (score 1):

We use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/index.html) at work, but I must confess that I haven't used them much since setting it up in our continuous integration server. NetBeans and other IDEs parse and display the docs when you hover over and auto-complete items.

Answer (score 0):

PHPdocumentor 2 is currently in alpha phase but still usable, so it seams that the project development ist continued.